# Is it OK to call GCM register() from more than one point in an Android app?

Tags: android, sdk, google-cloud-messaging

## Architecture

I'm building an Android SDK, which should receive push notifications from the SDK server. The backend of the enclosing app also sends push messages, and both backends share the same project id and key.

Therefore, the Google Play services `register()` is called twice - By the app, and by the SDK.

My main concern is that the consecutive call can harm the push sending mechanism - for example, by changing the `registrationId`, leaving either the SDK or the app with an outdated id.

### Notes

- Both `BroadcastRecievers` (for the SDK and the application) are registered in the manifest with the same category - the package name of application.
- Push sending seems to work well for now
- I am using the same `senderId` for the app and the SDK. In fact, the `senderId` is one of the SDK parameters.
- Both the app and SDK have the same `registrationId`

## Question

Does calling `register()` from the SDK and afterwards from the Application can cause any collision or deprecation?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell without debugging. But if you are segregating the detailed code in SDK from the UI code in the app for the sake of modular code, it would be a good idea to keep all the concrete code in the SDK. Backend code for GCM (registering, handling push notification, storing them) should be handle by SDK and not the app code. If you are doing that in both modules, yes there might be performance issues and also that would defeat the purpose of SDK..